# UpdateLayeredWindow blues on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I have a NET 2.0 Winforms app based partly on [this code](http://devblog.antongochev.net/2008/07/30/create-custom-ui-appearance-for-winforms-layered-form-part-5/). It features a form transparency using `UpdateLayeredWindow` API. It works perfectly on Vista and Windows 7 but fails on Windows XP.

I have narrowed it down to `UpdateLayeredWindow` failing with last error 8 (not enough memory). While experimenting I also found out that swapping (desired) `ULW_ALPHA` for either `ULW_COLORKEY` or `ULW_OPAQUE` works on XP but produces the wrong effect (the image shows but the transparency is wrong).

I am wondering if something is wrong the way PNG bitmap is being loaded and handled by NET internally and that there is something about it `UpdateLayeredWindow` dislikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's working, but the layered windows are not actually visible, I guess the opacity settings are wrong. With the code you linked to, changing line 67 in LayeredForm.cs from "BlendOp = 255" to "BlendOp = 0" fixes the issue for me (running on Windows XP SP3).

Comment: Marvelously simple! Thanks man! Too many hours wasted on this today and you saved the day. Brilliant.